# Firebase user read all, write new, but only modify his own data

Tags: authentication, firebase, rules

I have the next scenario on Firebase:

There are 2 things, **Users** and **events**.

I would like the **Users** to be able to create new **Events**, see all the existing events but be only able to modify only the events that were created by them.

Meaning that UserOne created EventOne, can see EventOne and EventTwo, but can only modify EventOne.

My structure is as follows:

```
-events
 -eventOne
    endTime: 
    id: 
    name: 
    providerId: 
    startTime: 
    userId: 
 -eventTwo
    endTime: 
    id: 
    name: 
    providerId:  
    startTime: 
    userId: 
-users
    -userOne
    -userTwo
```

And my current rules are pretty much the default ones:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in with an email and password
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },
     "events": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To ensure that all users can see all events, you can set the read-rule for events to either be `true` or `auth != null`, using the latter if you want to require that readers are at least authenticated.

To ensure that events can only be modified by their creator, record the original author alongside the event and validate it using `auth.uid`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "events": {
      "$eventid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null && (!data.exists() || data.child('author').val() === auth.uid) && newData.hasChild('author')",
        "author": {
          ".write": "newData.val() === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above, we use `!data.exists()` to check whether or not there is an existing event at this location. If no event exists, anyone can add one at this location. Next, `data.child('author').val() === auth.uid` ensures that if an event exists, only the author can modify it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!, and I just had to add 

`".read":"auth != null"`

below "rules" to make sure they could be read

Comment: is it same if i set `newData.hasChild('author')` in `.validate`?

Comment: @vzhen As long as you're also validating that the value of 'author' matches what you want it to be (i.e. something in the auth token).

Comment: @vzhen that's not really the same.