# Firebase DatabaseError: Permission denied

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to save some data on `Items` node in firebase. i was able to save when my rule was

```
"Items":{
   ".write": "auth != null",
   ".read": "auth != null"
}
```

but i want users to write/update their **own** items and **i don't want** to use `$` variable since it will add some data on my path. that is

**the below method will add some data on my path** instead of `/Items` it will be `/key/Items`

```
{


"rules": {
    "Items": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore, the best method that i saw was to write my rule like this

```
"Items":{
       ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "(data.exists() && data.child('userId').val() === auth.uid) || (!data.exists() && newData.child('userId').val() === auth.uid)"

}

}
```

When i run the below code on the simulator, everything is ok

```
 {
"userId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

**But** wnen i try to upload data from my phone, i get an error

```
setValue at /Items/-KWH6tgdLPGTdascf-w3 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way is to just check whether the id of logged in user is the same as id stored by `userId` variable before allowing the user to update and push the object to firebase.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
Item item;
if (user != null) {
   //logged in
   String uid = user.getUid();
   if(uid.equals(item.getUserId()){
    //allow the user to update item.
   }
} else {
  //not logged in
}
```

Answer (score -1):

set database read-write rules to `true`

```
"Items":{
   ".write": "true",
   ".read": "true"
}
```

Comment: but that will make everybody edit the data. i want only the data owners to do so

Comment: In that case you need to use `$` only , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736252/firebase-user-read-all-write-new-but-only-modify-his-own-data) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38600989/keeping-firebase-data-secure)

Comment: adding "$" will force me to include some extra data on my path. that is my database reference should point to `/items/key/`. i don't want to include any key

Answer (score -2):

As per last verion of realtime datebase, tr this:
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started?authuser=0](http://Rule%20Configuration%20Doc)

Add this on ur tab rule at Database:

```
    // Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```